# Latency issue with reachJS app running on AWS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

I have a reactJS app that allows a user to log into a financial service.  When I execute the app locally in my development machine, the time it takes to log the user into the system is somewhere around 5 seconds (I will explain below in more detail). When I execute the app from the AWS endpoint, the time it takes to log the user into the system is somewhere between 15 and 20 seconds.  I am trying to find out how to research where the bottleneck is.

The process that gets executed is this:

1. The app accepts a user ID and password.
2. The app calls a Web API (also hosted on AWS) passing it the user ID and password.
3. The Web API builds an mq message (IBM Websphere) and passes it to an mq message handler (also hosted on AWS).
4. The mq message handler sends the mq message to the financial institution for validation.
5. The mq message handler receives a response and sends the response back to the Web API.
6. The Web API receives the response and sends the response to the reactJS app.
7. If the response is valid, the reactJS app will now have specific pieces of data related to the user trying to log in. The app will call the Web API with an account ID (which was returned to the app by the Web API) to determine what type of account the user is in.
8. The Web API will take the account number, creates another mq message and send the message to the mq message handler.
9. The mq message handler sends the request to the financial institution for validation.
10. The Web API receives the response and sends the response to the reactJS app.
11. If the response is valid, we know the type of account the user is in. The app will now call the Web API and request all the data for the user.
12. The Web API takes the user id and account type, creates another mq message and send the message to the mq message handler.
13. The mq message handler sends the request to the financial institution for validation.
14. The Web API receives the response and sends the response to the reactJS app.
15. The home page is presented to the user with data from the financial institution.

All of the above works exactly as expected.  The only issue is the amount of time it takes for the initial round trip of step 2 and step 5.  I have console.log() statements in the reactJS to display date and time at all points specified above so I know it takes almost 19 seconds to execute step 2 - 5 when the app is executed from the AWS endpoint.

How do I determine what process (or processes) might be running on the AWS beanstalk environment that may be causing this delay?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry if my guess is wrong. Is Web API build on AWS serverless technology?

Comment: The Web API was developed in MS visual studio 2015 and deployed to an AWS beanstalk instance.